# How to check CONTAINS with multiple values

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to find all the zones that contain 2 or more zone members where the search term is a string value.   Here is the code I have.  In the FindCommmonZones method when I try to cast the result of an Intersect to an ObservableCollection I get a run-time on an invalid cast.  The question is, is there a better way to do this?   The string array that is the paramter for FindCommonZones() can be any count of strings.  StackOverflow had some other similar posts but none really answered my question - it looked like they all pertained more to SQL.

Some code:

```
public class Zone
{ 
    public List<ZoneMember> MembersList = new List<ZoneMember>();
    private string _ZoneName;
    public string zoneName{ get{return _ZoneName;}  set{_ZoneName=value;} }
        public Zone ContainsMember(string member)
    {
      var contained = this.MembersList.FirstOrDefault(m => m.MemberWWPN.
             Contains(member) || m.MemberAlias.Contains(member));

      if (contained != null) { return this; }
      else { return null; }

    }

}

 public class ZoneMember
    // a zone member is a member of a zone
    // zones have ports, WWPNs, aliases or all 3
{
    private string _Alias = string.Empty;
    public string MemberAlias {get{return _Alias;} set{_Alias = value; } }
    private FCPort _Port = null;
    public FCPort MemberPort { get { return _Port; } set { _Port = value; } }
    private string _WWPN = string.Empty;
    public string MemberWWPN { get { return _WWPN; } set { _WWPN = value; } }
    private bool _IsLoggedIn;
    public bool IsLoggedIn { get { return _IsLoggedIn; } set { _IsLoggedIn = value; } }
    private string _FCID;
    public string FCID {get{return _FCID;} set{ _FCID=value; } }
}


private ObservableCollection<ZoneResult> FindCommonZones(string[] searchterms)
    {

        ObservableCollection<ZoneResult> tempcollection = 
          new ObservableCollection<ZoneResult>();
        //find the zones for the first search term
        tempcollection = this.FindZones(searchterms[0]);

        //now search for the rest of the search terms and compare 
         //them to existing result
        for (int i = 1; i < searchterms.Count(); i++ )
        {  
           // this line gives an exception trying to cast
           tempcollection = (ObservableCollection<ZoneResult>)tempcollection.
             Intersect(this.FindZones(searchterms[i]));

        }

        return tempcollection;
    }
    private ObservableCollection<ZoneResult> FindZones(string searchterm)
    // we need to track the vsan where the zone member is found
    // so use a foreach to keep track
    {
        ObservableCollection<ZoneResult> zonecollection = new ObservableCollection<ZoneResult>();
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, Dictionary<int, CiscoVSAN>> fabricpair in this.FabricDictionary)
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<int, CiscoVSAN> vsanpair in fabricpair.Value)
            {
                var selection = vsanpair.Value.ActiveZoneset.
                           ZoneList.Select(z => z.ContainsMember(searchterm)).
                               Where(m => m != null).OrderBy(z => z.zoneName);
                if (selection.Count() > 0)
                {

                    foreach (Zone zone in selection)
                    {
                        foreach (ZoneMember zm in zone.MembersList)
                        {
                            ZoneResult zr = new ZoneResult(zone.zoneName, 
                            zm.MemberWWPN, zm.MemberAlias, vsanpair.Key.ToString());
                            zonecollection.Add(zr);
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

        }
        return zonecollection;
    }
```

Comment: Why does `ContainsMember` return the `Zone` instance? Shouldn't it just return `bool`? Then your check becomes `return this.MembersList.Any(m => m.MemberWWPN.Contains(member) || m.MemberAlias.Contains(member)))`.

Comment: hmmm... because that's the way I wrote it?  :)  Your code is simpler.  I don't think it occurred to me to return a bool. Thanks!

Comment: As a general rule - if a method of a class returns the parent instance of that class then you're probably over-complicating code somewhere as anyone calling that method always already has that instance. It would only make sense for a method on `Zone` to return the type `Zone` if that was a new instance, for example on a `Copy()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Intersect` is actually `Enumerable.Intersect` and is returning an `IEnumerable<ZoneResult>`. This is not *castable* to an ObservableCollection because it isn't one - it is the enumeration of the intersecting elements in both collections.

You can, however create a *new* ObservableCollection from the enumeration:

```
tempcollection = new ObservableCollection<ZoneResult>(tempcollection
    .Intersect(this.FindZones(searchterms[i]));
```

Depending on how many elements you have, how `ZoneResult.Equals` is implemented, and how many search terms you expect, this implementation may or may not be feasable (`FindZones` does seem a little overly-complicated with O(n^4) at first glance). If it seems to be a resource hog or bottleneck, it's time to optimize; otherwise I would just leave it alone if it works.

---

One suggested optimization could be the following (incorporating @Keith's suggestion to change `ContainsMember` to a bool) - although it is untested, I probably have my SelectManys wrong, and it really largely amounts to the same thing, you hopefully get the idea:

```
private ObservableCollection<ZoneResult> FindCommonZones(string[] searchterms)
{

    var query = this.FabricDictionary.SelectMany(fabricpair => 
        fabricpair.Value.SelectMany(vsanpair => 
            vsanpair.Value.ActiveZoneSet.ZoneList
            .Where(z=>searchterms.Any(term=>z.ContainsMember(term)))
            .SelectMany(zone => 
                zone.MembersList.Select(zm=>new ZoneResult(zone.zoneName, zm.MemberWWPN, zm.MemberAlias, vsanpair.Key.ToString()))
        )
    )
    .Distinct()
    .OrderBy(zr=>zr.zoneName);

    return new ObservableCollection<ZoneResult>(query);
}
```

Comment: thanks, I will look that.  Realistically I don't expect more than 2 or 3 searchterms.   Do you have any suggestions for a better implementation of FindZones()?  the important piece for me is tracking which VSAN the zones are found in.  that is why I was using a foreach().  I didn't see a way to do it with LINQ since I would be returning Zone objects that don't know what VSAN they belong to. I can provide the VSAN class listing if necessary.

Comment: ZoneResult.Equals isn't implemented, I guess I need to implement it.  Also, if there is a better way  to get the results I want, I don't have to do it the way I have it designed.

Comment: I don't think Intersect will do what you want unless you either implement Equals or provide a comparer, since the same result in two different collections will be two different objects.

Comment: I added a comparer that compares the ZoneResult by using the zone name.  I also changed it to this line of code:  `tempcollection = new ObservableCollection<ZoneResult>(tempcollection
                                      .Intersect(FindZones(searchterms[i]), new ZoneResultComparer()));`    That only returns the first ZoneResult that matches the Comparer, I need them all.  The comparer compares the ZoneName member of the ZoneResult class

Comment: thanks.  I figured out that I will have to change the design of the FindCommonZones() or change the design of FindZones().  I did not realize that if you have a list with multiple identical values, Intersect doesn't return all of them, it only returns 1.  I need all of them.

Comment: Ok I assumed since you were using Intersect and the returned result is identical, you wanted only one. Try Concat instead, or simply AddRange.

Comment: Well  I learned something - if the lists have duplicate values, Intersect only returns 1 value.  I also realized my EqualityComparer was flawed. It was only comparing 1 property of the ZoneResult class and it should have been comparing 2 of them.  I corrected that and the intersect is working the way I expected it to. :)